# Database Selection Failed. Unknown Database error on phpmyAdmin

Tags: php, sql, database, phpmyadmin, xampp

I am having trouble with selecting my database via PHP script on localhost.

I am 100% sure that db name is spelled correctly and infact it appears on phpmyAdmin very well and only when I am trying to connect to it by running a PHP script on localhost it displays the following error:

```
Database selection failed Unknown database 'fokrul_justdeals'
```

My PHP code is here:

```
<?php
    class database{
        public $connection;
        // the user for the database
        public $user = 'root';  
        // the pass for the user
        public $pswd = '';
        // the db from where you want to parse the info  
        public $db = 'fokrul_justdeals';
        // the host where db is located
        public $host = 'localhost';

        function __construct(){
            $this->connect();
        } 

        private function connect(){
            $this->connection = mysql_connect("$host", "$user", "$pswd") or die("Database connection failed ". mysql_error());
            if($this->connection){
                // we select the db that we want to work with
                mysql_select_db($this->db, $this->connection) or die("Database selection failed " . mysql_error());
            }
        }
```

I have read thousands of forums and I am doing everything as I shall be. But don't know what is going wrong here?

One interesting thing is that out of all databases only system generated db 'mysql' connects if I change the db name to 'mysql' in PHP script.

I have tried creating different db names and also tried creating new users and adding full privileges to them. Nothing has worked for me :(

Comment: Don't use mysql, use mysqli or pdo, it's deprecated

Comment: it still shows database selection failed. Why it is not working with mysql_connect?

Comment: Can you connect to the db with any other method, like MySQL Workbench or command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$this->connection = mysql_connect("$host", "$user", "$pswd") or die("Database connection failed ". mysql_error());
```

You should use

```
$this->host,$this->user,$this->pswd
```

Comment: Thanks mate. Now it says this

Database connection failed Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: your user or pass or host is incorrect

Comment: As you can see from my code above (PHP) I am using root user and it doesn't have any password, so it is kept blank. I have checked on phpmyAdmin root user have full privileges to fokrul_justdeals db

Comment: No you are not connecting. The problem is not your db. Are you sure your database root user has no password?

Comment: Yes, it says No password. I have checked it again

Comment: I tried setting a password and it still gives the same error!!

Comment: Try create another user with password and change your username and pass to new one.

Comment: Done it already mate. No luck!

Comment: Guys! This is interesting here!

I just tried keeping both username and password blank: it gave me database selection failed error. Unknown database 'fokrul_justdeals'

and, If I use valid username and password then it says: Database Connection failed. Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'(using password:NO)

Any thoughts?

Comment: Just want to take a moment to thank all wonderful people who helped me resolve this issue. Just to let you know that I found out that the fault was with the login details which I was suppose to use for MySQL server. Each of you have given me a reasonable solution and I really appreciate it. @MIIB

Comment: Your welcome @Tirath Singth. It's been a pleasure