# mysqli_connect() doesn't appear to be able to find the database

Tags: php, mysql

Ok so here is the connection.php code:

```
<?php

$dbCon = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","aparadekto2059","spitiinc");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
?>
```

I have created the database named "`spitiinc`" through `phpmyAdmin` but get the same error every time I try to connect to it:

> Failed to connect: Base(spitiinc) inconnue

I guess I have a french version of the program since this means, base unknown pretty much. Will also post 2 images of the error screen and additionally of the database existence. I tried to find answers in the site but from about 10 or so that I saw, they didn't have anything this basic and that's what troubles me. I have only made a bare-bones basic thing, and it doesn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated , thanks in advance

Here is the image:
http://s12.postimg.org/w1bsinwwd/wtf.jpg

Comment: Are you doing this on Unix/Linux? Database names are case sensitive, are you sure you got the case right?

Comment: nope , windows , and just posted the image

Comment: Can i see your database Collation ? should be latin1_swedish_ci

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15167064/database-selection-failed-unknown-database-error-on-phpmyadmin

Comment: @Josua It is , as stated in the phpMyadmin , "utf_general_ci" . The question you told me to check was once that i had seen before posting here but i have no errors in the syntax (right? not really sure but seems pretty simple) and the "root" account logs succesfully

Comment: Does it work if you select the `simplecms213` database in your connect function?